# Error installing Spyder in Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.7

Tags: python, installation, python-3.7, spyder, ubuntu-20.04

I got this error while installing Spyder in Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.7. It installs perfectly with Python 3.8 without any issue. Please help to fix this error.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: psutil, ujson
  Building wheel for psutil (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/ranick/.virtualenvs/ml/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gkngqlcn/psutil/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gkngqlcn/psutil/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-ioxnwy6h
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-gkngqlcn/psutil/
  Complete output (44 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
```